# not iterating each row from csv rows using PHP

Tags: php, csv

```
post_title
B Project Kodou Ambitious 0101 Boys Meet Girl
B Project Kodou Ambitious 0102 Boys Meet Girl
B J and the Bear 0110 Lobo
B J and the Bear 0111 Crackers
B O R N To Style 0101 Homeless Boy To Rock Star Glam
B O R N To Style 0101 Homeless Boy To Rock Star Glam
```

I have this csv file which have these type of strings in each cell. I want to seperate the text before 4 digits in each string. And I also want 4 digits in each string. Here is the code that I came up with so far.

```
$file = fopen('e.csv', 'r');

while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  $csv[] = $row;
}

$new_csv = array();
foreach ($csv as $row)
{
  $n = count($csv[0]);
  for ($q = 0; $q < $n; ++$q)
  {
    $new_row[$csv[0][$q]] = $row[$q];
    $new_csv[] = $new_row;
  }

  $title1 = ($new_row['post_title']); 
  $a_title = explode(" " ,$title1);
  $tot_a = count($a_title);

  $i = 0;
  foreach ($a_title as $session_episode) {
    $session_episode1 = preg_match_all('!\d!', $session_episode, $matches);
    if ($session_episode1 != 0 && $session_episode1 != '' && $session_episode1 == 4) {
      $j[] = $i;
    }
    $i++;
  }
  $len = $j[0];
  $a_title[$len];
  echo '<pre>' . var_dump($a_title[$len]) . '</pre>';
}
```

In this code, it does iterate the 4 digit from each string, but only for first 2 cells. I am new to php. Can anyone help me with how I can get 4 digits from each string with these csv rows. Thanks in advance

Comment: How is each cell separated, looks like everything is just spaces from what you posted... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want text before digit,digit and then text after digit in an array. Do like below-

```
<?php
    $array = [];
    if (($handle = fopen("e.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $i = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE) {
            $result = array();
            $index = 0;
            foreach ($data as $key=>$number) {
                if (is_numeric($number)) {
                    $index++;
                    $result[$index][] = $number;
                    $index++;
                }
                $result[$index][] = $number;
            }
            unset($result[2][0]);
            $array[] = [implode(' ',$result[0]),implode(' ',$result[1]),implode(' ',$result[2])];
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
?>
```

***Output at my local end:-***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => B Project Kodou Ambitious
            [1] => 0101
            [2] => Boys Meet Girl
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B Project Kodou Ambitious
            [1] => 0102
            [2] => Boys Meet Girl
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B J and the Bear
            [1] => 0110
            [2] => Lobo
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => B J and the Bear
            [1] => 0111
            [2] => Crackers
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => B O R N To Style
            [1] => 0101
            [2] => Homeless Boy To Rock Star Glam
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => B O R N To Style
            [1] => 0101
            [2] => Homeless Boy To Rock Star Glam
        )
```

This is how my CSV looks:-

[image]

Comment: @JaiMadhwan  glad to help you :):)